# Is there any way to block or disable Azure Active Directory B2C in a tenant?

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

Seems that only subscription contributor is required for someone to instantiate AAD B2C in a tenant.  This is a potentially huge security concern as it is outside of normal management controls.  I haven't seen/found any way to disable/remove once it's in place - am I missing something or is this just out of administrative control entirely?

Comment: Do you want to delete the B2C tenant?

Comment: No, disable (availability of) the service within the core tenant.  There are security, compliance and privacy implications with an internal subscription owner publishing to external consumers.

Comment: **Contributor** is almost a permission role second only to **Owner**. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/built-in-roles#all. I don't think the permission to create a B2C tenant is too big for a contributor. We cannot disable B2C service in AAD. You should plan the allocation of RBAC role more carefully.

Answer (score 0):

**Contributor** is almost a permission role second only to Owner. See [Azure built-in roles Contributor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/built-in-roles#contributor).

I don't think the permission to create a B2C tenant is too big for a contributor.

We cannot disable B2C service in AAD. You should plan the allocation of RBAC role more carefully. For example, assign some roles with less authority than the contributor role. Or [customize your RBAC role](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/custom-roles) to meet your needs.

Comment: I understand RBAC and roles management.  Owner/contributor should have full control over the scope of a subscription, yet B2C is at the tenant scope.  Just as with admin consent, IMO there should be controls over this service.

Comment: @MikeHickey Although B2C is at the tenant scope, it's also a service under subscription. And B2C is a tenant completely independent of the AD tenant. Admin consent is for the concept of tenants. For a service of subscription, Azure currently uses RBAC role to control access permissions. As long as the condition of the role is met, it has the right to access the corresponding service. Hope this is helpful to your understanding of Azure subscription / tenant.